# Removing component when clicked react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I am new to React I have problem how to remove component when clicking button next to the component. In the code below I have passed 'click' via props to the Currency component assigning it to 'onClick' event handler.  I hope it should remove component when clicking button. However, I feel that I am doing something wrong - nothing happened.
Can anybody help me please.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";
    import Currency from "./Currency";


     class Currencies extends Component {
      state = {
        inputField: 0,
        exRates: 0,
        opened: true,
      };

      [....]

      BTCChangeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({ inputField: event.target.value });
      };

      removeComponentHandler = () => {
        this.setState({ opened: false });
      };

      render() {
        [...]


        return (
          <div>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Enter BTC value"
              onChange={this.BTCChangeHandler}
            />
            <Currency name="USD" value={usd} click={this.removeComponentHandler} />
            <Currency name="GPB" value={gbp} click={this.removeComponentHandler} />
            <Currency name="EUR" value={eur} click={this.removeComponentHandler} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Currencies;
```

Comment: You want to remove currency component bound to that button?

Comment: Yes. Each component has a button and upon 'click' I would like to remove the component

Comment: please check my solution below, it is for all the currency component.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onClick` not `click`

```
<Currency name="USD" value={usd} onClick={this.removeComponentHandler} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";
    import Currency from "./Currency";


     class Currencies extends Component {
      state = {
        inputField: 0,
        exRates: 0,
        opened1: true,
        opened2: true,
        opened3: true,
      };

      [....]

      BTCChangeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({ inputField: event.target.value });
      };

      removeComponentHandler =(name)=> () => {
        this.setState({ [name]: false });
      };

      render() {
        [...]


        return (
          <div>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Enter BTC value"
              onChange={this.BTCChangeHandler}
            />
            {this.state.opened1?
            <Currency name="USD" value={usd} click= 
            {this.removeComponentHandler("opened1")} /> :null}
            {this.state.opened2?
            <Currency name="GPB" value={gbp} click= 
            {this.removeComponentHandler("opened2")} /> :null}
            {this.state.opened3?
            <Currency name="EUR" value={eur} click= 
            {this.removeComponentHandler("opened3")} /> :null}

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Currencies;
```

Comment: This will unmount all the currency component but if you want to remove only one the in similar fashion you can do for each currency component and use different state value for each

Comment: Thank you. Well, it deletes all components. I need one by one.

Comment: Modified the code as per your requirement. Please up vote if that solves your issue.